# GoLang JWT with Martini throwing <invalid Value>?

Tags: go, jwt-go

I'm trying the JWT middleware examples to get JWT to work with Martini and it's giving me an  return when it hits the authentication handler.

Here's the code, straight from the examples..

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware"
    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
    "github.com/go-martini/martini"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    StartServer()

}

func StartServer() {
    m := martini.Classic()

    jwtMiddleware := jwtmiddleware.New(jwtmiddleware.Options{
        ValidationKeyGetter: func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
            return []byte("My Secret"), nil
        },
        SigningMethod: jwt.SigningMethodHS256,
    })

    m.Get("/ping", PingHandler)
    m.Get("/secured/ping", jwtMiddleware.CheckJWT, SecuredPingHandler)

    m.Run()
}

type Response struct {
    Text string `json:"text"`
}

func respondJson(text string, w http.ResponseWriter) {
    response := Response{text}

    jsonResponse, err := json.Marshal(response)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(jsonResponse)
}

func PingHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    respondJson("All good. You don't need to be authenticated to call this", w)
}

func SecuredPingHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    respondJson("All good. You only get this message if you're authenticated", w)
}
```

If I hit the unauthenticated route, it works. If I hit the authenticated route, it tells me I need a token. If I hit the authenticated route with a token that's not right, I get an error stating,

```
signature is invalid
<*errors.errorString Value>
```

So all that works. If I hit the authenticated route with the right token, it gives me  as the return text. I can't find out why. This is straight from their example, though I get the same in my personal project.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
m.Get("/secured/ping", jwtMiddleware.CheckJWT, SecuredPingHandler)
```

Try this instead

```
m.Get("/secured/ping", jwtMiddleware.Handler(SecuredPingHandler))
```